# swift 3 facebook sdk get friends list

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk, facebook-ios-sdk-4.0

I need to get all my friends list:

I found this code:

```
var fbRequestFriends: FBSDKGraphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "/{friend-list-id}", parameters: [AnyHashable : Any]())

fbRequestFriends.start { (connection, result, error) in
    if error == nil && result != nil {
        print("Request Friends result : \(result!)")
    } else {
        print("Error \(error)")
    }
}
```

But in return I get this error:

> Error Optional(Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1002 "unsupported
>   URL"
>   UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=(null)?access_token=EAAZAaT5Yj9qQBABsXA5KGpwvGX6wIdgX6h9mLtzz6YtgjiOB12XwWxl1MrDJLtZChWSOOKXDiizZCu7uZAixBmqP97HYUXkeg3lkTeeeyjmvhZBOZBibrp2Exa9uZB7V5fflJTvISF2aqK94H7E52svqei6SHvxi3W9vcynSI8hPQBBSawND9NHQif0wYIPuHIpbzl6ErBErvk6nm4ysMo1ZA0BFHVmflVYZD&format=json&include_headers=false&sdk=ios,
>   NSErrorFailingURLKey=(null)?access_token=EAAZAaT5Yj9qQBABsXA5KGpwvGX6wIdgX6h9mLtzz6YtgjiOB12XwWxl1MrDJLtZChWSOOKXDiizZCu7uZAixBmqP97HYUXkeg3lkTeeeyjmvhZBOZBibrp2Exa9uZB7V5fflJTvISF2aqK94H7E52svqei6SHvxi3W9vcynSI8hPQBBSawND9NHQif0wYIPuHIpbzl6ErBErvk6nm4ysMo1ZA0BFHVmflVYZD&format=json&include_headers=false&sdk=ios,
>   NSLocalizedDescription=unsupported URL, NSUnderlyingError=0x7a6285b0
>   {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1002 "unsupported URL"
>   UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLKey=(null)?access_token=EAAZAaT5Yj9qQBABsXA5KGpwvGX6wIdgX6h9mLtzz6YtgjiOB12XwWxl1MrDJLtZChWSOOKXDiizZCu7uZAixBmqP97HYUXkeg3lkTeeeyjmvhZBOZBibrp2Exa9uZB7V5fflJTvISF2aqK94H7E52svqei6SHvxi3W9vcynSI8hPQBBSawND9NHQif0wYIPuHIpbzl6ErBErvk6nm4ysMo1ZA0BFHVmflVYZD&format=json&include_headers=false&sdk=ios,
>   NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=(null)?access_token=EAAZAaT5Yj9qQBABsXA5KGpwvGX6wIdgX6h9mLtzz6YtgjiOB12XwWxl1MrDJLtZChWSOOKXDiizZCu7uZAixBmqP97HYUXkeg3lkTeeeyjmvhZBOZBibrp2Exa9uZB7V5fflJTvISF2aqK94H7E52

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: do you actually want to get the "friends" or the "friendlists"? there is a difference. btw, you can only get friends who authorized your app too and the api call is /me/friends.

Comment: `/me/friendlists` resp. `/friendlist-id` will only get you info about the list itself anyway (like the list name); it will not give you the users _on_ those lists.

Comment: @luschn How does it know which friends have authorized the app?

Comment: because those are the ones you get with /me/friends.

Answer (score 11):

@CBroe is right, this is how the code should look like

```
let params = ["fields": "id, first_name, last_name, name, email, picture"]

let graphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "/me/friends", parameters: params)
let connection = FBSDKGraphRequestConnection()
connection.add(graphRequest, completionHandler: { (connection, result, error) in       
    if error == nil {
        if let userData = result as? [String:Any] {
            print(userData)
        }
    } else {
        print("Error Getting Friends \(error)");
    }

})

connection.start()
```

Comment: {
    data =     (
    );
    summary =     {
        "total_count" = 235;
    };
} . not getting list

Comment: Bista please tell me why it is not giving the data

Comment: What is the output? Any Error or message?

Comment: i found **{ data = ( ); summary = { "total_count" = 235; }; }**

Comment: It only returns Facebook friends who have also signed up to your app, not the full list.

Comment: @LukeStanyer how does it know which FB friends have signed up to the app?

Comment: FB collects and keeps track of this automatically. Everybody that signs up to your apps gets added to a user list on FB servers and gets assigned a user id unique to your app that will never change.

Comment: how to get friends list in ios